# write images to csv files with python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have a set of images and corresponding information I would like to store in a csv file like this:

```
file_info 1 | file_info2       | image
some info   |  other info      | 121 127 ...a lot of number ... 130 128
```

This is just one example row, but there would be as many rows as I have images.

How would I do this? I have been trying with(again just for one row to begin with)

```
with open('Fail.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('some_info','other_info',image.flatten()))
```

This gives me three columns as it should, but the image cell is bad --instead of being 45163008
space delimited pixel values the cell just contains the abbreviated python output as [121 127 ..., 130 128] ... meaning, two problems...1) it does not write all the numbers out and 2) it prints the brackets.

I also tried pandas DataFrames, but there it was difficult to insert arrays/lists of numbers in individual cells.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest the Base64 encoding, which is included in Python.

Comment: What is `image` for kind of object and what does `.flatten()` do?

Comment: 45M space separated ascii values? 200M column?

Comment: The images are jpegs which I have load in using `skimage.io.imread`.  Once loaded in they are each stored in an array of size (3168, 4752, 3).  Running `.flatten()` on this converts the (3168, 4752, 3) array to an array of size (45163008,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `base64` which encodes a binary data in the format of an ASCII string. Try the following code:

```
encodedImage = base64.b64encode(open('path/to/your/image.ext', 'rb').read())
```

Comment: When retrieving you'll need to decode the Base 64 string to binary to get the stored image,

Comment: This works, although I would have liked to have stored the image as the list of numbers produced by `.flatten()`